# C# reading binary file text into a string

Tags: c#, string, null, streamreader

I have these text lines within binary data:

```
 "TUNGUSKA_D.Decal_M.Tunguska_Logo_M.Lights_M.N_ReactiveCage.M_ReactiveSide.M_KitAtlas.GlassTint_M.."
```

If I use the following:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(path));
sr.BaseStream.Position = 9840;
string MeshNamesInString = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

It only returns `"TUNGUSKA_D"`

It seems to read only to the Null(.) and stops. How do I get the whole string?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure the file really has all the text? If you open the file in a binary file reader like the one that comes with VisualStudio, do you see the whole text there? If you post more code or details about the code, that might help problem solve.

Comment: C 'ruined' whole generations with the null terminated strings. If that file is in some sort of binary format, treat it as one and don't try to turn everything into a string or funny things will happen. Can you elaborate on the file format?

Comment: It is a binary file(unknown format) it contains unknown data in the beginning, but I though that offset(9840(dec) where text starts) should take care of that.

Comment: @DainiusGintalas OK, I get the unknown part to a certain degree; let's call the first 9840 bytes an "unknown header" and ignore them. However, since you plan to use the remaining bytes, you should know something about the content. You list "TUNGUSKA_D.Decal_M...." but based on your results, I have to assume that the "." after "TUNGUSKA_D" is something else - maybe a NULL character '\0' and not really the '.' char which would be '\x2E'; the streamreader should be able to handle nulls as well so there might be another problem. Care to share the file?

Comment: Thank you bkdc I have it working now, indeed it was a Null char inbetween the strings. So I just read file into chars[], and converted it into string, then used .split('\0') and it works fine now. Thanks again for the replies.

Comment: @DainiusGintalas Cool! I don't think that you need to go through char[] - `string MeshNamesInString = sr.ReadToEnd();var list=MeshNamesInString.Split('\0');` should work equally well as long as there are no other 'weird' chars that can corrupt your string.

Answer (score 1):

try using the same library but with different appraoch.
 `File.ReadAllText();`